# Frames not working in HTML

Tags: html

I am learning HTML and was creating frames which is not working for me. not sure why, below is my code, Please suggest on reason why it is not working. Browser renders me a blank page.

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
Frames
</title>
</head>
<body>
<frameset cols="25%,75%">
<frame src="Links.html" name="links"/>
<frame src="Main.html" name="content"/>
</frameset>
</body>
</html>
```

Links HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
Links
</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Links</h3>
<ul style="link-style-type:square">
<li> <a href="Main.html" target="content">Home</a></li>
<li> <a href="Contactus.html" target="_parent">Contact us</a></li>
</ul>
<h3>Search</h3>
<ul style="link-style-type:square">
<li> <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Google.com</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Main.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
Main
</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3 align="center">Welcome to Foddies</h3>
<p>
-: About us :-

Established in 2015. We are a leading food chain spread in 23 countries with all type of cusines :)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which browser you are looking at ? version ?

Comment: @Vivek Firefox 31.0, not working in chrome also

Comment: To use frames on a page use <frameset> tag only instead of <body> tag. refer to my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `frameset`  must not be inside `body` tags.

see this [w3 recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/frames.html).

change your code to this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
         <title>
              Frames
        </title>
    </head>


    <frameset cols="25%,75%">
         <frame src="Links.html" name="links"/>
         <frame src="Main.html" name="content"/>
    </frameset>

    </html>
```

Also as suggested here, `frame` is now deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

The [`frame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frame) tag is depricated and the functionality is removed from most browsers.

Edit: I would suggest using an [`iframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) instead.

Answer (score 0):

> To use frames on a page use `<frameset> tag` only instead of `<body>`
>   tag.

Also `Frames` are `deprecated` in HTML, I would rather suggest go for `iFrame` tags.